# how can i check return value of stored procedure in entity framework

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I have a stored procedure call but i want to get the return value of the stored procedure. Return type is integer. Following the code where I am calling the stored procedure

```
 else if(ReportName=="LandMarkInOutReport")
        {
          _DBContext.LandMarkInOutReport(report.ReportParameters.StartDate, report.ReportParameters.EndDate, Convert.ToInt64(paramArr1[3]), Convert.ToInt32(paramArr1[9]), Convert.ToInt32(paramArr1[11]), paramArr1[5], paramArr1[7]);     
        }
```

So please guide me how can I get the return value and also that is it the correct way to call stored procedure in entity framework?

Comment: `int returnVal=_DBContext.LandMarkInOutReport(report.ReportParameters.StartDate, report.ReportParameters.EndDate, Convert.ToInt64(paramArr1[3]), Convert.ToInt32(paramArr1[9]), Convert.ToInt32(paramArr1[11]), paramArr1[5], paramArr1[7]);` This should work.

Comment: @Mairaj bro it returns vonversion error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Database First**

First, you have to add your stored procedure to the *.edmx* file.
If you have a context variable *_DBContext* and the stored procedure is called *LandMarkInOutReport*, you can execute it like this:

```
LandMarkInOutReport_Result returnValue = _DBContext.LandMarkInOutReport(report.ReportParameters.StartDate, report.ReportParameters.EndDate, Convert.ToInt64(paramArr1[3]), Convert.ToInt32(paramArr1[9]), Convert.ToInt32(paramArr1[11]), paramArr1[5], paramArr1[7]).FirstOrDefault();
```

The stored procedure call without `.FirstOrDefault()` isn't executed on the database.

Now you can use the *returnValue* to call the correct variable eg.: *returnValue.ReturnVariableName*.

**Code First**

You can call the stored procedure with *.SqlQuery<>*:

```
int returnValue = _DBContext.SqlQuery<int>("LandMarkInOutReport @StartDate, @EndDate, @param3, @param4, @param5, @param6, @param7", 
                  new SqlParameter("StartDate", report.ReportParameters.StartDate), 
                  new SqlParameter("EndDate", report.ReportParameters.EndDate), 
                  new SqlParameter("param3", Convert.ToInt64(paramArr1[3])), 
                  new SqlParameter("param4", Convert.ToInt32(paramArr1[9])), 
                  new SqlParameter("param5", Convert.ToInt32(paramArr1[11])), 
                  new SqlParameter("param6", paramArr1[5]), 
                  new SqlParameter("param7", paramArr1[7])).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: i want the returning value

Comment: That's what *returnValue* is... Does your SP returns a value? Are you using Code First, Database First,..?

Comment: stored procedure returns integer...its code first i think

Comment: stored procedure is added in edmx file but if i do like you said , it gives error of conversion

Comment: @User123 edmx? Then it's database first? Can you post the error?

Comment: Error: Cannot implicitly convert type DataEntities.LandMarkInOutReport_Result to int

Comment: @User123 Does the first option work now? Entity Framework creates a class when using a stored procedure in database first. That class is returned and should have a property that is called exactly like your output parameter in your SP.

Comment: it works but return value is null...Can you please guide me why the returnvalue is null ?

Comment: @User123 Then your SP doesn't return a value. Try executing your SP with the same parameters in a database management studio and check what it returns.

Comment: i have executed the SP in sql , it is executed successfully but no value is returned...Thank you so much Loetn

Comment: Dear Loetn do you know how to add image on web page in MVC before complete loading of the contents of the page ?

Comment: @User123 No, I do not. You better create a new question for that :)